# Vagrant provision multiple playbooks with multiple ssh users

Tags: ssh, vagrant, ansible

I'm trying to provision a vm using vagrant's ansible provisioner. But I have two playbooks and both need to use different ssh users. My use case is this, I have a pre-provisioning script that runs under the `vagrant` ssh user that is set up by default. My pre-provision script then adds a different ssh user `provisioner` that is set up to ssh onto the VM with its own key. The actual provision script has a task that deletes the insecure vagrant user on the system so it has to run as a different ssh user, `provsioner`, the user that the pre-provisioner creates.

I can not figure out how to change the ssh user in the Vagrantfile. Example below is how far I've gotten. Despite changing the `config.ssh.username` vagrant always sets the ssh user to the last value, in this case `provisioner` and that doesn't authenticate when running the pre-provision script because it hasn't been created yet.

Can I override the ssh user somehow? Maybe with an ansible variable itself inside the `do |ansible|` block (below)?

Is what I'm trying to achieve possible? It seems so straightforward I'm shocked I'm having this much trouble with it.

```
VAGRANTFILE_API_VERSION = "2"

Vagrant.configure(VAGRANTFILE_API_VERSION) do |config|
  config.vm.box = "base_box"
  config.vm.box_url = "s3://bucket/base-box/base.box"
  config.vm.network "private_network", ip: "10.0.3.10"
  config.ssh.keep_alive = true
  config.vm.define "vagrant_image"

  config.vm.provision "ansible" do |ansible_pre|
    config.ssh.username = "vagrant"
    ansible_pre.playbook = "provisioning/pre_provisioning.yml"
    ansible_pre.host_vars = {
      "vagrant_image" => {
        "ansible_host" => "127.0.0.1",
      }
    }
    ansible_pre.vault_password_file = ENV['ANSIBLE_VAULT_PASSWORD_FILE']
  end

  config.vm.provision "ansible" do |ansible|
    config.ssh.username = "provisioner"
    ansible.playbook = "provisioning/provisioning.yml"
    ansible.host_vars = {
      "vagrant_image" => {
        "ansible_host" => "127.0.0.1",
      }
    }
    ansible.vault_password_file = ENV['ANSIBLE_VAULT_PASSWORD_FILE']
  end
end
```

(In case you were wondering the s3 box url only works because I've installed the `vagrant-s3auth (1.3.2)` plugin)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can set it in several places. Vagrantfile (but not `config`, it will be overridden), through Ansible extravars:

```
  config.vm.provision "ansible" do |ansible_pre|
    ansible_pre.playbook = "provisioning/pre_provisioning.yml"
    ansible_pre.host_vars = {
      "vagrant_image" => {
        "ansible_host" => "127.0.0.1",
      }
    }
    ansible_pre.extra_vars = {
        ansible_user: "vagrant"
    }
    ansible_pre.vault_password_file = ENV['ANSIBLE_VAULT_PASSWORD_FILE']
  end

  config.vm.provision "ansible" do |ansible|
    ansible.playbook = "provisioning/provisioning.yml"
    ansible.host_vars = {
      "vagrant_image" => {
        "ansible_host" => "127.0.0.1",
      }
    ansible.extra_vars = {
        ansible_user: "provisioner"
    }
    ansible.raw_ssh_args = "-i /path/to/private/key/id_rsa"
    ansible.vault_password_file = ENV['ANSIBLE_VAULT_PASSWORD_FILE']
  end
```

But you can also write a single playbook and switch users inside. See `ansible_user` and [`meta: reset_connection`](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/modules/meta_module.html).

Comment: Thanks, that's similar to what I ended up doing. I added `"ansible_ssh_user" => "vagrant"` to host_vars. That paired with the lines below got me done.

    config.ssh.insert_key = false
    config.ssh.private_key_path = ["~/.ssh/id_rsa-provisioner", "~/.vagrant.d/insecure_private_key"]

Comment: You can also specify the key in `raw_ssh_args` option in Vagrantfile (I added an example).